# Convert children to proper way in parent constraint layout Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

Hey I am working in android Constraint layout. In my xml I used constraint layout with linear layout. I want to know is there in any way, I can use only constraint layout remove other children layout like linear layout.

**item_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/item_selector_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            tools:text="25mg" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subtext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            tools:text="from $1.65" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tagContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/item_tag_background"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:visibility="visible">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tagText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My view look like this

[image]

I only want to achieve this through constraint layout.

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely a way to do it. Something like this may work for you:

```
<ConstraintLayout>
  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/text
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
     tools:text="25mg" />

  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/subtext"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
     android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
     android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tagText"
     tools:text="from $1.65" />

  <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tagText"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:paddingStart="10dp"
     android:paddingEnd="10dp" 
     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/subtext"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

Just pull the child layouts out and constrain the views the way that you want them.

Note: This is not exact. You may have to play with the constraints to get them the way you want it.

Comment: what about second linear layout ?

Comment: @vivekmodi Edited to add text view from second layout

Comment: In my first linear layout I used a background called **item_selector** and I put my second linear layout over it. But how can I shoe first linear layout background?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `View` behind them to set background for the first two `TextView`s like,

```
<ConstraintLayout
   ...>

   <View
     android:id="@+id/backgroundView"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="0dp" 
     android:background="@drawable/item_selector_background"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/text"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/subtext"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/subtext"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/subtext"/>

   <TextView
     android:id="@+id/text"
     ...
   />

   <TextView
     android:id="@+id/subtext"
     ...
   />

   <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tagText"
     ...
   />

   ...
</ConstraintLayout>
```

the height and width of the backgroundView can be constrained to match the first two `TextView`s